# How drag and drop a circle in D3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm in the middle of a project and I need to give this ball interactivity. When I click, I need the ball to follow me and when I release it to stay there. I tried this but it doesn't work. The problem is in the last lines, when I executed the on.mousdown, on.mouseup and on.mousemove but I don't knok how to fixed.

Thanks!

```
console.log(d3)

let screenHeight = 700
let screenWidth = 1200

let isDown = false;

let sizes = [   
    {r:100},
]

//Create canvas
function createSVG() {
    let container = d3.select('#container')
    svg = container.append('svg')
    .attr('id', 'canvas')
    .attr('width', screenWidth)
    .attr('height', screenHeight)
    .style('background-color', 'black')
}
//Create circle
function build() {
    let dragging = false
    let circle = svg.selectAll('circle')
      .data(sizes)
      .enter()
      .append('circle')
        .attr('cx', function(d,i){return screenWidth/2})
        .attr('cy', function(d,i){return screenHeight/2})
        .attr('r', function(d,i){return d.r})
        .style('fill', 'red')
        .on('mousedown', function(d,i){
             dragging = true
        })
        .on("mouseup", function(d, i){
            dragging = false
        })
        .on("mousemove", function(d, i){
                let coords = d3.mouse(this)

                circle = d3.select(this)
                if(dragging === true) {
                    circle.attr('x', coords[0])
                    circle.attr('y', coords[1])
                }
            })
}

function main() {
    createSVG()
    build()
}

main()
```

Comment: _"I tried this but it doesn't work."_ Please describe what doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The attributes for an svg circle's center coordinates are `cx` and `cy`, not `x` and `y`. Replace those and this ought to work.

Comment: Sorry, I see that you knew that already when you create the circle, just do the same in `mousemove` :)